# ウェブコンテンツでよく見かけるこの山型マークは画像ですか？テキストですか？

Tags: javascript, html, css

赤で囲った部分ですが、テキストで出力するにはどうすればいいでしょうか？
論理和、論理積記号よりも横長なようですが。

[image: モバイル版Wikipediaのスクリーンショットです。「概要」「オープニングクロール」という節タイトルの左横に山型の、矢印の頭の部分だけをとったような記号が書かれており、それらが赤色で囲われています。]

Comment: どうすれば出来るか不明ですが、半角の三角括弧を縦書きや回転させて使うとか？ [CSS3で縦書きにする方法と挙動](https://qiita.com/RinoTsuka/items/3e3eaaba8cddb6ff08e9), [CSSのtransform:rotateで画像や文字を回転させる方法](https://allabout.co.jp/gm/gc/406310/)

Answer (score 3):

そのシェブロン (あるいは矢印) <sup>[[1]](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/uxguide/ctrl-progressive-disclosure-controls?redirectedfrom=MSDN#progressive-disclosure-controls-1)</sup>は**画像**です。質問文のスクリーンショット元と思われる [Wikipedia において](https://ja.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/%E3%82%B9%E3%82%BF%E3%83%BC%E3%83%BB%E3%82%A6%E3%82%A9%E3%83%BC%E3%82%BA/%E3%82%B9%E3%82%AB%E3%82%A4%E3%82%A6%E3%82%A9%E3%83%BC%E3%82%AB%E3%83%BC%E3%81%AE%E5%A4%9C%E6%98%8E%E3%81%91)は、 `background-image` プロパティにより、背景画像として表示されており、 SVG 形式となっています。

[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]

Comment: div要素の中に「::before」だけ記述されていますが、こうするとcssのbefore疑似要素が表示されるのでしょうか？

Comment: @user32639 さん> CSS にて `div` 要素の `before` 疑似要素を宣言して、それに対して `background-image` プロパティを適用することで、このようになります。

Answer (score 1):

Wikipediaは[MediaWiki](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/MediaWiki/ja)特有のものを使っていますが、ほとんどの場合はアイコンフォントのライブラリを使用しています。有名なものとしては、[FontAwesome](https://fontawesome.com/)や[GitHub Octicons](https://octicons.github.com/)でしょう。その他にも多数あり、下記のリンク先でいくつか紹介されています。

- [Icons · Bootstrap](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.4/extend/icons/)
- [無料で商用利用できる便利なアイコンフォント10選](https://uxmilk.jp/53664)
- [Webアイコンフォントはどれを使うとよいか](https://www.softel.co.jp/blogs/tech/archives/4095)
- [【2019年版】おすすめのWebアイコンフォントと使い方まとめ](https://webdesign-trends.net/entry/2310)

アイコンの種類、利用条件、使い方、対応ブラウザーなどはフォントによって異なります。それぞれの公式サイトをよく読んでからお使いください。

ほとんどの場合、ファイル類を置いて、CSSを読み込んで、指定のタグに指定のclassを付けるだけです。詳しい仕組みは割愛しますが、古いブラウザでも対応する場合はwebfontを使う場合が多いです。他にも、CSSにSVGを組み込んでいるもの、JavaScriptでSVGに置き換えるもの、より発展したものでは、ReactやVue.js等のJSフレームワークと組み合わせて他のタグのようにおくとSVGにレンダリングされるもあります。フロントエンドだけではなく、サーバーサイド側でSVGに置き換えてしまうと言ったものまであります。ここら辺の技術は、CSS以外にもJavaScriptおよびSVGについて詳しくならないと理解できません。まず、ただ使うだけであれば、それぞれのライブラリに書いてある方法で使うことが無難でしょう。